# Blackberry - How to get Category of BlackBerryContact?

Tags: blackberry, addressbook, contacts, rim-5.0

I have not found any fields in JDK 5.0.0 for getting Category of BlackBerryContact.
If there are any alternative way for getting Category of BlackBerryContact then please suggest....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try PIMItem.getCategories()

[public String[] getCategories()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/pim/PIMItem.html#getCategories%28%29) - Gets all the categories to which this item belongs. If there are no categories assigned to this item, a zero length array is returned.